# ListPreference with multiple fields

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I am writing an Android app (API 16, but I can increase it if needed) which uses PreferenceFragment to modify the app's settings.

Everything works fine, but I would like to have a `ListPreference` object with three fields instead of just one like this:

[image]

How can I implement that? I thought about subclassing `Fragment` but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MyPicker](https://github.com/cheng7692019/MyPicker):

[image]

At least you can see how it is implemented.